# Why is parent class causing error in deserialization of sub class?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a sub class "PositionClass" of a large partial class "SymbolDataClass". I not able to add [Serializable] tag to SymbolDataClass:

```
public partial class SymbolDataClass
{
    public bool StateSaved = false;

    [Serializable]
    public class PositionClass
    {
         Public bool Var;
    }
}
```

I am able to Serialize PositionClass without issue.

However, on Deserialization I get the following error referencing the parent class. Why?

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Type 'Matrix.Matrix+SymbolDataClass' in
>   Assembly 'Matrix, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: I hate to be "that guy", but honestly: BinaryFormatter is essentially deprecated. It is known to be a security hole, as well as being inefficient. It also has limited support in .NET Core 3, and even that limited support is grudging (meaning: they really wanted to do less, but were forced to increase the support to "limited"). It is also hugely brittle. Any other serialization technology would be a better choice.

Comment: @MarcGravell Can you recommend the closest tech to it please?

Comment: That really depends on your intended usage. I'm a big fan of protobuf-net, but I'm hugely biased!

Comment: PositionClass is a [nested type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types) so its type name includes the containing type's name.  But I can't reproduce any sort of problem serializing `SymbolDataClass.PositionClass` from and to binary; see https://dotnetfiddle.net/oasFhf (.Net 4.7.2) and https://dotnetfiddle.net/GwmGzB (.NET Core 3.1.0) for demos of successful serialization and deserialization.  Can you share a [mcve]?